# Web Scraping links from previously found link

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm

I am web scraping a website that contains open [Christmas tree farms](http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/) in the United States. My end goal is to obtain phone names, numbers, address, and emails for each farm. Though this is my end goal, I have not coded that far, so please only help me where I am stuck. I'd also like to stick as close to my code as possible so that I can understand it (I am very new to this), but of course am grateful for other suggestions.

I first grabbed the home website where there is a table of states with embedded links. I was able to collect all those links here in my first block of code. Within the states, there is a map that shows each county (with another embedded link). I am now trying to grab each of those links. I was able to do one state with something similar to my first block of code shown, but I want to loop through to eliminate unnecessary/repetitive code. I tried creating a loop, but I am getting an error in regards to my `.text` command. I assumed that each link I grab needs to have a `.text` at the end like what my `source` variable has. So I tried adding it, but there's obviously a problem. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

```
source = requests.get('http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
concatenate = 'http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/'

find_state_group = soup.find('div', class_ = 'alert')
for link in find_state_group.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'xmastrees' in link['href']:
        states = concatenate + link['href']
```

```
i = 1
for source_state in states:
    source_state = states[-1 + i:]
    x = source_state().text
    soup_state = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
    state_county = soup_state.find('div', class_='alert')
    for county_link in state_county.find_all('area', href=True):
        if '.php' in county_link['href']:
            county_link_update = concatenate + county_link['href']
            print(county_link_update)
    i = i + 1
```

```
    x = source_state().text
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that for each source_state link, you need to make another `requests.get(url)` to get the content of that page. I'm a bit confused by your states = concatenate + link line. Shouldn't you be storing all the states in a list? The second for loop seems to look like you have done that.

Comment: Should I have `x=requests.get(source_state).text`. Yes, `states` should be in a list. I noticed that it wasn't when I tried to just index the first 5 links. How do I get that into list form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply to my comment, I have modified your solution with a few minor changes. You should be able to follow this logic for getting and navigating to each link in your map.

1. I created an empty list `state_links` at the beginning.

   - For each state link we find, I append it to that list.
2. For each state link in state_links, we make a new request to get the text content of that page.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
concatenate = 'http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/'
state_links = []
ab = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID','IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA',
          'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK',
          'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
ab = [x + "xmastrees.php" for x in ab]
find_state_group = soup.find('div', class_ = 'alert')
links = find_state_group.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    if link['href'] in ab:
        states = concatenate + link['href']
        state_links.append(states)
print(state_links)

for link in state_links:
    source = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    area_links = soup.find_all('area', href=True)
    area_links = [concatenate + x['href'] for x in area_links]
    print(area_links)
```

Comment: I believe this works, except I am running into multiple errors. I believe the problem is that the states table attached above includes other countries as well as the District of Columbia and Wash DC (which are not states) and do not follow the same county format (picture 2). So I think we need to pass a `pass` command to skip over invalid "states"???

Comment: There are only two ways I can think of to perform what you are asking. 1. Create another list (hardcoded) with the urls of those countries and check before you add it to the list. 2. Use a try except to catch when going to a non-state page throws an error.

Comment: I think the try and except would be best to use because those countries have similar formatted links in the first block of code. So it would be difficult find which link they are. Though if we made a list with all the states abbreviations and made the `if` statement look for those abbreviations....?

Comment: The ideal way is the if statement, rather than forcing an error and catching it.

Comment: okay, so I need to fix my first if statement to say `if abbreviation in link['href']:`

Comment: And create a list with all the state abbreviations?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
concatenate = 'http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/'
state_links = []
ab = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID','IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA',
          'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK',
          'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
ab = [x + "xmastrees.php" for x in ab]

find_state_group = soup.find('div', class_ = 'alert')
links = find_state_group.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    if link['href'] in ab:
        states = concatenate + link['href']
        state_links.append(states)
print(state_links)
```

```
i = 1
for source_state in state_links:
    source_state = states[-1 + i:]
    x=requests.get(source_state).text
    soup_state = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
    state_county = soup_state.find('div', class_='alert')
    for county_link in state_county.find_all('area', href=True):
        if '.php' in county_link['href']:
            county_link_update = concatenate + county_link['href']
            print(county_link_update)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: What do you think this line does? `source_state = states[-1 + i:]`

Comment: It should actually be `state_links[-1 + i:]`. I think that line is grabbing the first index of the `state_links` list you created. Hhhhmmmm, guess that wouldn't make sense since the I didn't put anything on the second end of the `:`. So it's just grabbing the index I want and then all the rest after it??

Comment: Ahhh yes, that was the problem. I removed the `:` and it worked!

Comment: So that's still incorrect. The for loop is already responsible for iterating over the list of state_links and presenting each individual link in source_state. Then you reset source_state to be another element from state_links, which does not make sense. That quoted line is not needed.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So I was repeating the same step.